# Neyman-Pearson test with normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Given one random variable $X$ from a normal distriution with parameteres $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=\theta$. Find critical area of neyman pearson test with $\alpha=0.1$. I know why it is $\{x^2<c\}$ but i know that $c=0.25$. Why is that? 
$H_0:\theta=4$,$H_1:\theta=1$

Comment: What are the null and the alternative hypotheses?

Comment: my mistake added to the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to Neyman-Pearson Lemma, we have to find $k>0$ such that
$$
\frac{L(\theta_1;X)}{L(\theta_0;X)} \ge k \, ,
$$
so reject $H_0$ if
$$
\frac{C_{\theta_1}\exp\{-x^2/(2\theta_1)\}}{C_{\theta_0}\exp\{-x^2/(2\theta_0)\}} \propto \exp\{x^2/2(1/\theta_0 - 1/\theta_1)\} = \exp\{ - 15x^2/32\} \ge k.
$$
or equivalently if
$$
x^2 \le c .
$$
Thus,
$$
0.1 = \mathbb{E}_{H_0}I\{x^2 \le c\} = \mathbb{P}(x^2/4 \le c/16) = F_{\chi ^2(1)}(c/16),
$$
Finally,
$$
c = 16\chi^2(0.1)_{(1)}\approx 0.25.
$$

Comment: Is your $C$ independent of $\theta$? We have a Normal distribution here.

Comment: You are right, I've changed the notations to be more precise. But it does not effect the answer.